# Java Map<String,String> data null error

Tags: java, dictionary, nullpointerexception

I am using map collection in Java. My code is below;

```
public void example(String var){
Map<String, String> params = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

params.put("data", var);

String jsonResult = Jsoup.connect(url).ignoreContentType(true).data(params).execute().body();
}
```

When var is null, I take an error which is `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data value must not be null`.

Comment: as far as i know, its valid to put null referenced objects to a Map.. the `IllegalArgumentException` is not coming from the `put` statement, can you please post your stack trace. Also split up your long chained function to multiple lines (issue must be in that line), so you  can clearly see where the issue is..

Comment: As the exception says: Data value must not be null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error seems to be in `Jsoup#data` that doesn't accept `null` value for any param. If you know `var` is `null`, then don't add the key/value pair in the map.